# Ruby Hash Values is Array, need to convert to string

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash of integers as keys and arrays of strings as values.  I need to convert this to a new hash that inverts this relationship with each item from the array of strings in the original hash values becoming a key in the new hash and each original key becoming the associated value.  For example:

```
original = {1 => ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2 => ['g', 'm', 'z']}

new_hash = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 1, 'g' => 2, 'm' => 2, 'z' => 2}
```

I'm struggling to extract the items from the original array values.  It's easy enough to do

```
original.each { |k, v| new_hash[v] = k }
```

but this keeps the original array as the new key.  I've tried doing something like

```
original.each { |k, v| new_hash[v.each { |i| i }] = k }
```

but this also returns the original array for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another one, via [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
original.flat_map { |k, v| v.product([k]) }.to_h
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "g"=>2, "m"=>2, "z"=>2}
```

Comment: All the responses are great, but this seems the most "ruby" way to do it.  Much thanks for introducing the product method to me.

Answer (score 2):

the below snippet will give what you want, but let me think on a more readable and elegant solution.

```
newhash = {}

original.each do |k,v|
  v.each do |v2|
    newhash[v2] = k
  end
end
#=> {1=>["a", "b", "c"], 2=>["g", "m", "z"]}

newhash
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "g"=>2, "m"=>2, "z"=>2}
```

Comment: `original.each_with_object({}) { |(k, vs), h| vs.each { |v| h[v] = k } }` would work.

Comment: i was looking to documentation for a suitable method. need to commit to memory those below -))

Answer (score 2):

```
original.flat_map { |k, vs| vs.map { |v| {v => k} } }.reduce(&:merge)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is close. You'll have to iterate each element in the values array when assigning the new key/value pair to the newHash

```
newHash = {}
original.each { |k, v| v.each {|i| newHash[i] = k}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
original.map { |number, ary| Hash[ary.map { |char| [char, number] }] }.reduce(&:merge)
```